# UITableView clicking on an item an opening a new screen/view/activity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view(HomeViewController) consisting of items as:

1. locations
2. Reporting
3. Setting

I am having these items as separate files(LocationViewController,ReportingView Controller and Setting ViewController).Now if user clicks on location a new screen/activity/view should be open and same for rest items.
Can some one please help.my code is as:

```
    #import "HomePageController.h"  @implementation HomePageController
    @synthesize menuList, table;
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {

    menuList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:

              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"LOCATIONS",nil],

              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"REPORTING",nil], 

              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SETTINGS",nil],

              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"PASSWORD",nil],

              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"HELP",nil],

              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ABOUT",nil],

              [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHARE",nil],
              nil];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];  
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor]; 
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;    
    self.title=@"CoinRead";     
    [table reloadData];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)theTableView{
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 40;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return menuList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    }

    cell.highlighted=NO;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    NSArray *rowArray = [menuList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *nameLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 8, 200, 20)]autorelease];

    nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[rowArray objectAtIndex:0]];

    nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    nameLabel.shadowColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    nameLabel.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.5);

    nameLabel.textColor = RGB(0,0,0);

    [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f]];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement below method of `UITableViewDelegate`  to get the selection event

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```